# Xcode 9.2 doesn't support iOS 11.3

Tags: xcode

Tried to test my app on my phone, and got this error.

> This iPhone 6 is running iOS 11.3 (15E216), which may not be supported
>   by this version of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Rookie mistake. I forgot I upgraded to the latest iOS.

Checked I was on Xcode 9.2, then checked the App Store upgrades section and sure enough there is an upgrade to 9.3.

2.49 GB downloaded, installed, fixed the issue.

Comment: I guess you're running High Sierra. I'm still on Sierra. This happened to me as well. I guess I will be forced to upgrade my Mac Mini Server from what I have found online.